# How to migrate AWS Amplify project to another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have a React application with AWS Amplify as its backend. I'm using AppSync API and DynamoDB database to save data. AppSync API is the only category that I provisoned in my project.

| Category | Resource name | Operation | Provider plugin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Api | testAPI | No Change | awscloudformation |

**I need to clone this same AWS Amplify backend to another AWS account easily.**

Yes, I could create another Amplify project and provision resources one by one. But is there any other **easy method** to move this Amplify backend to another AWS account?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution through [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3350) (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3350) Github issue thread. But I'm not 100% sure whether this is the recommend method to migrate Amplify resources.
These are the steps that I followed.

- First, I pushed the project into a GitHub repo. This will push only the relevant files inside the `amplify directory`. (Amplify automatically populates `.gitignore` when we initialize our backend using `amplify init`).
- Clone this repo to a new directory.
- Next, I removed the `amplify/team-provider-info.json` file.
- Run `amplify init` and you can choose your new AWS profile or you can enter `secretAccessKeyId` and `accessKeyId` for the new AWS account. (Refer this [guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/react/#option-2-follow-the-instructions) to create and save an IAM user with AWS Amplify access)
- This will create backend resources locally. Now to push those resources, you can execute `amplify push`.

If you want to export the Amplify backend using a CDK pipeline, you can refer to this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/export-amplify-backends-to-cdk-and-use-with-existing-deployment-pipelines/